# SQL script/query to get user not logged in for last 10 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing MySQL script and query. I have a Table User. Table User only contain some basic data. I know that I have to create a table to store the log.

I want to display the ID, User Name, and Last successful login date.

```
SELECT 
  usersloggedin.id, 
  users.name, 
  usersloggedin.dateloggedin 
FROM
  users 
  INNER JOIN usersloggedin ON users.id = usersloggedin.id 
WHERE 
  usersloggedin.dateloggedin BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND NOW()
GROUP BY userslogged.id
ORDER BY dateloggedin;
```

So, is there any recommended solution? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I've reformatted your sql so it's not all on one line, for readability. Please consider formatting future SQLs similarly - align your SELECT FROM WHERE GROUP etc, and then indent the bits underneath each one, starting every join, where clause and selected column on a new line to help visually define "what goes together"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN, change your WHERE to AND, and put a new WHERE clause of `usersloggedin.ID is null’. You don't need the group by.

You have all your users, and you have a list of some of those users that have logged in in the last 10 days. The left join will put nulls for any users that have not logged in in 10 days, so we just ask the where clause to pick them out. We often call this an anti join

There are other ways to skin this cat: "select from users where UserId not in (select userid from logins in the last 10 days)", and "select from users x where not exists(select anything from logins where UserId = x.userid and logindate in the last 10 days)" being common ones

This answer intentionally contains no code because this seems like homework, but you're very close to figuring it out, keep going!

Comment: Is this the right way? Sorry if I'm asking, I'm new to sql

SELECT 
  usersloggedin.id, 
  users.name, 
  usersloggedin.dateloggedin 
FROM
  users 
  LEFT JOIN usersloggedin ON users.id = usersloggedin.id 
AND 
  usersloggedin.dateloggedin BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND NOW()
WHERE usersloggedin.id IS NULL
ORDER BY dateloggedin ASC;

Comment: Seems reasonable.. I should have also pointed out to remove the order by, as ordering by login date for users hat haven't logged in no longer has any meaning

Comment: The ASC is part of the OrderBy

Comment: You can't in the query you have, because login date isn't available.. you'll have to add another join to the data you want, something like `inner join (select UserId, max(logindate) as lastlogindate from userlogins group by UserId) mostRecentLogins ON users.id = mostRecentLogins.UserId` And then order by lastlogindate

Comment: It is an alias for a subquery. In sql tables are "blocks of data" with a width (number of columns) and a height(number of rows). A select command produces "a block of data", probably of different dimensions but a block of data no less. This block of data can be fed into another query via a join just like a table can.. in the end there should be no tables in your mind, just blocks of data. JOINs make blocks wider, UNIONs generally make them taller, WHERE make them shorter and SELECT generally make them narrower. Think of sql like a data reshaping exercise

Comment: Is this a new question? I thought you wanted the last login dates of the users who have not logged in in the last 10 days, which means you need `users INNER JOIN (last login grouping) LEFT JOIN logins WHERE .. IS NULL` ie two joins